# Wordpress localhost results in 404 pages when changing permalink structure to postname

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I want to have my permalink structure to %postname% but doing so makes every page go to a 404 page where the requested URL cannot be found on the server.
I'm using a mac and run my own development server using mac's php and apache. I followed this guide to get the server up: http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-osx-109-mavericks

These are the steps I took and none of them worked:

1. Edited my htaccess

`Options +FollowSymlinks`
`RewriteEngine on`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~wayne/plugin-dev/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~wayne/plugin-dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

1. Made sure rewrite engine is on for /etc/apache2/httpd.conf by uncommenting
   `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so`
2. Also made sure `AllowOverride` was set to all.

The only way it will work somewhat is if I use a custom permalink structure and put `index.php/%postname%/` but then all my pages will have a index.php in front of it and I don't want that.

Comment: You doing it wrong `/~wayne/plugin-dev/index.php` should only be `/index.php`. Because you already mentioned the `RewriteBase /~wayne/plugin-dev/`. Also `~` character exists on your URL?

Comment: The only thing I added was the `Options +FollowSymlinks` and `RewriteEngine on` The others wordpress automatically generated those. There is a ~ because that's how I can access my server files using `http://localhost/~username/`. I followed the instructions of setting up a lamp server with the link I provided above.

Answer (score 1):

Simple go to your WAMP folder. In WAMP go to bin; then apache. In apache there is a folder name conf; in conf there is a file name httpd. Open that file with note pad and find out this line `#LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so`

By removing hash from this line will enable the mod-rewrite function. Then you can use any custom permalinks for your site.

If need further help then let me know; I will send you a complete file or setup of WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

@Mehreen's answer was so close to correct. I was having this issue as well, pulling my hair out.

Here's what you need to do:
Go to wamp/bin/apache/apache[YourVersion]/conf
Open up httpd.conf in notepad or whatever.

Do a search for both of these lines:

```
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
```

(and)

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

If there are hashes (#) at the start of these lines, remove them (this uncomments those lines), and those modules will be enabled.

Exit WAMP and restart. Presto!